# Trane heat only in fan mode

Tags: heating

I have a older Trane electric furnace, the heat only works when I have it in Fan on -heat, I get only a click when it is in auto-heat mode.

thanks!

Comment: What model is the furnace? Can you post a wiring diagram?  Also, what make and model is your thermostat?

Comment: I bypassed stat, shorting r/w. model number looks to be bwv024a100d2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check your thermostat mode

"Electric furnaces" require the thermostat controlling them to control the fan (G) wire instead of managing the fan for the thermostat, so you need to put your thermostat in electric mode instead of fossil/gas/oil mode.  Check the documentation for your thermostat for details -- some older models use a jumper, slide-switch, or DIP switch, while newer models use a software setting that can be accessed through maintenance menus.

Comment: so shorting the r/w makes no difference then? the stat is in elec mode, a switch inside stat

Comment: @GregJohnson -- try shorting R to both W and G

Comment: if that works is it the stat? was wondering if a open heat coil could make the blower not run when in auto, is that possible?

Comment: @GregJohnson -- probably not an open heat coil.  if shorting R to W and G works, then it's the stat.

Answer (score 0):

When the thermostat calls for heat, it should energize the 'W' terminal in the stat. (As long as the 'R' terminal has full time 24-volts) That terminal in turn should have a white wire connected to it.  This wire should be connected to the heaters of the sequencers in the furnace.  This will start the heat.

Comment: there are no sequencers in the unit, only the fusible type links is what I see

Answer (score 0):

The fan is often times controlled with the sequencers also. When the first element starts the fan will start also. The sequencers are the switching mechanism that actually turns on the power to the elements.  (They are sometimes switched by contactors but far more often by sequencers.) In the base of these sequencers there are tiny elements that produce heat when 24-volte are applied across them.  This in turn warps bimetallic discs that actually close that contacts to energize the elements. If you don't understand this please get professional help.  These furnaces operate on 240-volts; not the kind of power to mess around with if you are not qualified. P.